# Flextable: repeat headers without changing column class

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, flextable

For very long tables, it can be useful to repeat headers for better visibility. One could do it manually beforehand on the dataframe by using `names()` and making that new column with `tibble::add_row` for example.

However, the issue is that columns need to be of the same class, so if you want to add the column names, you have to transform your columns to character, which in turn prevents `flextable` from properly formatting numbers.

Function `add_body()` is the closest thing to my needs (https://davidgohel.github.io/flextable/reference/add_body.html). It precisely allows you to add new rows in the body of the table. However, it doesn't allow you to choose on which row you want it added exactly (like `tibble::add_row` does); there are only two options: top or bottom. Additionally, for the new row, one must specify each cell/column individually, so we cannot rely on `names()`.

Is there any way to accomplish what I am describing? Thank you.

Edit: Even with `add_body()` I am getting an error adding a new row with different class, in this case with dates:

```
Error in as.POSIXlt.character(x, tz, ...) : 
  character string is not in a standard unambiguous format
```

Indeed, as written in the documentation:

> It is important to insert data of the same type as the original data,
> otherwise it will be transformed (probably into strings if you add a
> character' where a double' is expected). This keeps the ability to
> format cell contents with the colformat_* functions, for example
> colformat_num().

Edit: my best workaround is this:

```
library(dplyr)
library(flextable)
ft <- flextable(head(iris))
ft %>%
    add_footer_row(values = names(iris),
                   colwidths = rep(1, length(names(iris))))
```

Although the extra row lies at the bottom, it is still better than not having this information show again.

### Edit 2022-01-06:

It seems @jrcalabrese's solution works well for the sample data I provided (`iris` dataset). Here is a demonstration that it works even with different column classes (such as date, numeric) and conditional formatting.

```
library(dplyr)
library(flextable)
iris2 <- cbind(iris, date = as.Date("2021-01-06"))
head(iris2) %>%
    mutate(across(everything(), as.character)) %>%
    add_row(Sepal.Length = "Sepal.Length", 
            Sepal.Width = "Sepal.Width",
            Petal.Length = "Petal.Length",
            Petal.Width = "Petal.Width",
            Species = "Species",
            date = "date", .before = 4) %>%
    flextable() -> ft2
ft2
ft2 %>%
    bg(i = ~ Petal.Length < 1.5,
       j = ft2$col_keys,
       bg = "grey")
```

Unfortunately, as mentioned by @jrcalabrese, it is not possible to automatize this process using `names()`, so we have to define each row name manually.

### Edit 2022-01-07:

@romainfrancois [has provided a tidiverse fix](https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/issues/4632) to avoid defining row names manually through a custom `add_row2()` function. Here's a slightly adapted version:

```r
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
library(flextable, warn.conflicts = FALSE)

# Define our new custom function
add_row2 <- function(.data, x, ...) {
  add_row(
    .data, 
    tibble(!!!setNames(x, names(.data))),
    ...
  )
}

# Add a date column
iris2 <- cbind(iris, date = as.Date("2021-01-06"))

# Add the header row
head(iris2) %>%
  mutate(across(everything(),
                as.character)) %>%
  add_row2(names(iris2),
           .before = 4) -> iris2
iris2
#>   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species       date
#> 1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa 2021-01-06
#> 2          4.9           3          1.4         0.2  setosa 2021-01-06
#> 3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa 2021-01-06
#> 4 Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species       date
#> 5          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa 2021-01-06
#> 6            5         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa 2021-01-06
#> 7          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa 2021-01-06

# Make the flextable
ft2 <- flextable(iris2)
ft2 %>%
  bg(i = ~ Petal.Length < 1.5,
     j = ft2$col_keys,
     bg = "grey")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-01-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

### Edit 2022-01-15:

Unfortunately the solution above does not work for numeric formatting like formatting decimals:

```
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
library(flextable, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
    
# Multiply by a thousand to experiment with digit separators
iris2 <- iris*1000

# Make the flextable
ft2 <- flextable(iris2)
ft2 %>%
  colformat_double()    
# This works
```

[image]

```
# Define our new custom function
add_row2 <- function(.data, x, ...) {
  add_row(
    .data, 
    tibble(!!!setNames(x, names(.data))),
    ...
  )
}

# Add the header row
head(iris2) %>%
  mutate(across(everything(),
                as.character)) %>%
  add_row2(names(iris2),
           .before = 4) -> iris2

# Make the flextable again
ft2 <- flextable(iris2)
ft2 %>%
  colformat_double()
# This doesn't work (i.e., it doesn't format digits with the comma after thousands)
```

[image]

```
<sup>Created on 2022-01-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>
```

Comment: Do you have a reprex of what kind of data you're working with?

Comment: @jrcalabrese I'm so sorry I forgot to add this line defining the dataframe in my example, `ft <- flextable(head(iris))`, I was using the `iris` dataset as shown in the `flextable` help functions. I've edited my answer to reflect this correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is probably a better way to do this, but I think it satisfies your requirements. It involves converting it to a `huxtable` and then a `flextable` but unfortunately the title rows have to be manually added for every nth row. You could also suggest this as a potential feature on the `flextable` Github.

```
library(tidyverse, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
library(flextable, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
library(huxtable, warn.conflicts = FALSE)

head(iris, 15) %>% 
  mutate(across(everything(), as.character)) %>%
  add_row(Sepal.Length = "Sepal.Length", 
          Sepal.Width = "Sepal.Width",
          Petal.Length = "Petal.Length",
          Petal.Width = "Petal.Width",
          Species = "Species", .before = 6) %>%
  add_row(Sepal.Length = "Sepal.Length", 
          Sepal.Width = "Sepal.Width",
          Petal.Length = "Petal.Length",
          Petal.Width = "Petal.Width",
          Species = "Species", .before = 11) %>%
  as_huxtable() %>%
  set_bold(row = 1, col = everywhere) %>% 
  set_bold(row = 7, col = everywhere) %>% 
  set_bold(row = 12, col = everywhere) %>%
  as_flextable() %>% 
  border_outer() %>% 
  border_inner_h()
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer! It seems to work well for the sample data I provided (`iris` dataset). I wasn't sure if it was going to work with some columns in date format and with some conditional formatting on the supposedly numeric values, but it does work! I have edited my question to show that. Well done. Still troublesome to have to define column names manually though, but seems like there's no workaround.

Comment: Also, it is actually possible to replicate results similar to yours without the use of `huxtable`, by simply replacing `as_huxtable()` with `flextable()`.

Comment: Note that I have updated my question again this time with a `tibble::add_row` fix from @romainfrancois to avoid manually defining all row names.

Comment: Unfortunately, the solution does not work for formatting decimals with `colformat_double()`. See my updated question.

Comment: Another huxtable feature that might be useful is `split_across()`. `head(iris, 15) |> as_huxtable() |> set_header_rows(1, TRUE) |> split_across(after = c(5, 10))` will give you three tables with 3 headers. You can then join them back up with `rbind()`.